# Failed to parse server's response: Unknown type: nil

Tags: java, apache-camel, xml-rpc

Im trying to make a camel route that would get a xml-rpc data from a 3rd party web site. Problem is that some values are NIL. Is there some way to configure route to accept such values?

site: https://i.ifne.eu/om3-dev/ca/xml-rpc/get-upcoming-events-compact

In a worst case scenario i could pre-process it and replace all NIL`s, but i would like to know if there is not some simple solution

EDIT: adding example route

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://mainTimer?period=5000"/>
    <to uri="xmlrpc:https://i.ifne.eu/om3-dev/ca/xml-rpc/get-upcoming-events-compact?defaultMethodName=test" />
    <to uri="mock:result" />
</route>
```

Also I tried to play with XmlRpcClientConfigurer but had no luck there - im a java noob so no idea if im doing it right

```
public class xmlrpcConfigurer implements XmlRpcClientConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureXmlRpcClient(XmlRpcClient client) {
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl clientConfig = (XmlRpcClientConfigImpl)client.getClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);    

    }

}
```

Idea behind that was that acording to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC nil tag is an extension I dont really know if it does what i think it does...

Comment: Please share the code

Answer (score 1):

Well i was not able to find a solution so i have to solve it another way - im removing the `nil` elements

```
<dataFormats>
    <xmlrpc id="xmlrpcResponse" request="false"/>
</dataFormats>    
<route>
    <from uri="timer://mainTimer?period=60000"/>
    <to uri="https://i.ifne.eu/om3-dev/ca/xml-rpc/get-upcoming-events-compact?defaultMethodName=test" />
    <process ref="removeNilFromXml"/>   
    <unmarshal ref="xmlrpcResponse"/>
    <to uri="mock:result" />
</route>
```

removeNilFromXml.java:

```
public class removeNilFromXml implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String nonildata = data.replace("<nil/>", "");  

        exchange.getIn().setBody(nonildata);
    }

}
```

Not the best solution but it works...